# Win10 (and 8.1) boot performance mysteriously sluggish

Tags: performance, windows-10

I upgraded to 10 from 8.1 recently (and 7 before that). On login, I let a bunch of programs I need autostart and go into the systray: procexp (for monitoring), chat clients, tools like super-f4 and flux, etc. This autostart situation has barely changed for years and shouldn't take long either because they're all fairly light programs.

On 7, things went quickly after login and my systray filled up with the necessary icons like they came from a machinegun. Ever since I got 8 and 10, that speed has decreased a lot, to the point where I'm waiting a long time for things to start but Windows barely seems to be doing anything at all. I've changed my antivirus and various other factors, and nothing helps. It seems to be Windows itself that's holding things down somehow.

I have a fast SSD, 8GB RAM, no particular problems of any kind, etc.

I did a check yesterday with windows performance recorder, and this is the graph overview:

[image]

The CPU is idling half the time, my ssd isn't doing much, RAM is plenty.

Other people basically see their performance scale up until one resource is bottlenecked, which is how I want it. What could possibly be making my post-login startup take so long? I read vague hints here and there that newer Windows delays startup artifically for those people who don't want their PC to bottleneck a resource after login (which TBH is counterproductive), but can't find anything hard about this.

There is no recurring slew of errors in event viewer on login, so that's not it either.

What else could be slowing me down?

Comment: share the compressed ETL file, so that I can take a look at it.

Comment: @magicandre1981 https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3357590/WPR%20Files.7z

Answer (score 0):

When you open the ETL in WPA, click on `Profiles`->`Apply`->`Browse Catalog` and select the file `FullBoot.Boot.wpaprofile` you see this overview:

[image]

and see that the longest delay happens during the WinlogonInit phase (27 seconds).

> The WinLogonInit subphase begins when SMSSInit completes and starts
>   Winlogon.exe. **During WinLogonInit, the user logon screen appears, the
>   service control manager starts services, and Group Policy scripts run.
>   WinLogonInit ends when the Explorer process starts.**
>
> Visual Cues  WinLogonInit begins shortly before the logon screen
>   appears. It ends just before the desktop appears for the first time.
>
> **WinLogonInit Performance Vulnerabilities**
>
> Many operations occur in parallel during WinLogonInit. **On many
>   systems, this subphase is CPU bound and has large I/O demands.** Good
>   citizenship from the services that start in this phase is critical for
>   optimized boot times. Services can declare dependencies or use load
>   order groups to ensure that they start in a specific order. Windows
>   processes load order groups in serial order. Service initialization
>   delays in an early load order group block subsequent load order groups
>   and can possibly block the boot process.

In your case it is not the CPU or disk. The Delay comes from typing in your password (RequestCredentials takes 16s).

Next the logon of the user itself also takes 4s:

[image]

Do you now use a Microsoft account? Maybe the network is not stable enough and causes the delay.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. But no, I use an offline account. I also use a fingerprint scanner to log in, and login itself usually takes mere seconds. The delay of 16s may be due to me waiting for wifi to connect before logging in (since logging in without a connection screws up some of my programs). What I meant with slow startup is the whole part post-login though: the starting of my autorun programs when my desktop appears. Those programs take far too long to start up, and my CPU and disk are doing nothing in that time. That is what I'm curious about: it was much, much faster on 7.

Comment: reduce the number of tool in startup or use hibernation all the time like I do. Here you don't need to care about delay of startup programs

Comment: that's a non-solution... Are you implying windows (> 7) just sucks particularly at running autoruns quickly for some reason, that there isn't really anything to do about it? My problem is not that things take a long time, it's that programs that should start pretty quickly and simultaneously (they did on 7) now start one-by-one with a huge delay in between, making the overall process take way too long and filling it with idle time while they could perfectly all run at once and start up as quickly as my hardware can manage.

Comment: Win8/10 run a lot of store apps at startup (in WIn10 Cortana, the new Startmenu) and those start much slower compared to normal Win32 desktop applications