# Windows 10 SSD seems to have become slower in startup

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd

I have upgraded my laptop with a samsung 840 Pro SSD (instead of an HDD). When I first migrated to SSD windows was starting to load lightning fast and after a few seconds I was already at the password screen. Now it seems that it takes a while (at least 5 seconds but I haven't actually checked with my watch) before it starts loading windows and I have to wait more before reaching the password screen.

I tried to check the UEFI boot menu and I found two entries. I deleted the entry that did not involve the system partition and I got an unbootable disc... I fixed it from the commandline and now I have 3 entries in the boot menu and a slow boot procedure as before! Two of them are identical. Does the boot menu have anything at all to do with the slowing down? Is is an SSD issue? Kaspersky? Anything else?

edit: here is a screenshot of easyUEFI and MiniTool applications.

[image: link to the screenshot]

And another one from DISKPART:

[image: DISKPART screenshot]

Comment: Do you have multiple storage devices installed in your device?  Describe in detail how you migrated your installation?

Comment: @Ramhound I have one HDD installed instead of the DVD device. I didn't change the configuration from the migration onward but the boot time increased. The migration was done using samsung's migration utility...

Comment: Which drive has your boot partition on it?  *I am not asking which drive has Windows.*  I suspect the reason your boot times are slow is because your system is detecting two installation, and it has to figure out, which installation your trying to boot to

Comment: @Ramhound There is only one installation in the SSD. No installation in the HDD. The HDD is used for storage only. I checked the partitions on MiniTool and seen that I have quite a lot of them! There are seven of them and two unallocated spaces. One of the unallocated spaces was deliberately there for the better function of the SSD. I also have a WINRESTOOLS, ESP, a 128MB partition (no NTFS, no FAT), a 450MB Recovery(?) partition, a hidden 100MB and 488MB partition which contains Dell recovery files... I don't know if it makes any sense...

Comment: Post the BCD entry information (text).  With that information I also need a visual representation (screeshot) of the partitions on both drives.

Comment: @Ramhound added to question... To my surprise the 3 entries in the UEFI menu have become only 1! I had two of these (I mean the one in the image) and one with a different GUID yesterday and I haven't tampered with it at all... It seems that the second HDD (I noticed it just now) has an installation from my older lenovo laptop. The installation was there when the SSD was fast and is still here that it's slower.

Comment: If you remove the hdd does the system boot?  There is an odd 200MB partition that tells me Windows was installed on that hdd

Comment: @Ramhound Yes it does... I've done it in the past. I removed the HDD to put back the DVD. It booted fine. Windows was installed on the HDD. It contained the installation of my older laptop (windows 7). I've never had conflicts with it though. And the system was SSD+HDD from the start. The slowdown occurred later.

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run WPRUI.exe, select **First Level**, **DiskIO**, **FileIO** and under **Performance Scenario** select **Boot**. **Number of iteration** can be set to **1** and click to start. This reboots Windows and captures all activity during boot. After the reboot let the countdown tick to 0 to capture 2 minutes of activity after boot. Zip the large ETL file into zip/RAR file, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here. here I can see in detail what Windows is doing

Comment: @magicandre1981 Tried to do it... now I do have a huge file (2GB) but the program did not finish properly. It hanged for too long and I had to shut it down. It also informed me about security issues with spreading these files around, so I can't do it. Thanks anyway! It would be great if you could help me analyze these files on my own - if it's simple enough to do...

Comment: I've shown here how to analyze it: http://superuser.com/a/987176/174557 look which part of boot is slow. the warning is only shown that other users can see file /program names, but not the content (I would see a folder C:\mysecretpronstuff, but not the content of the files ;) )

Comment: @magicandre1981 Here it is: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7vjpZ2W3XYMc2Fhb1Q3WVgzYkk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I loaded the ETL into WPA.exe, I clicked on `Profile`-> `Apply`, "`browse catalog`" and select the file `FullBoot.Boot.wpaprofile` I saw this overview

[image]

So Boot is done in 30s to desktop (here a delay of 10s is in WinLogon-Phase where you enter your password). Most part is the Postboot (starting applications at startup) and so the complete boot takes 1 minute. So reduce the number of tools that automatically run when Windows boots.

I also see in the DiskIO graphs a lot of DiskIO from Kaspersky. Try a different AV suite like Avast and look if it makes Windows faster.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and trouble to have a detailed look at it! My main issue is that I've noticed a slower response when I first power on the laptop. It takes more time (although I haven't used a stopwatch to see how much) to start booting windows. That's why I asked whether the UEFI boot menu has anything to do with it, or it's something else. I know I've got enough applications but what was strange for me is that the same system used to load faster, so I don't understand what could be making the difference.

Comment: UEFI/BIOS time is not recorded in the trace. open taskmgr an look at "last BIOS time" in startup tab. Is this a large number. Mine is 5,2 seconds.

Comment: It's not... It's 3,6 seconds. I just thought that it was kind of instantaneous in the past. I do have a longer windows boot time due to kaspersky, I've noticed that but it was the boot time that had surprised me because I believe that installations have nothing to do with it. It's just the BIOS, right?